# prevent native select dropdown to be open on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari

On windows devices I found that the dropdown is opened on mousedown event so I can prevent it when I call preventDefault fucntion of mousedown event.

Is it possible prevent native select dropdown to be open on iOS when it is clicked even with javascript?

For accessibility reasons disabled attribute is not a solution.

```js
  var select = document.getElementById("test"),
        mousedownSpan = document.getElementById("mousedown"),
        focusinSpan = document.getElementById("focusin"),
        focusoutSpan = document.getElementById("focusout");
        
    
    select.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      select.focus();
      mousedownSpan.textContent = parseInt(mousedownSpan.textContent) + 1;
    });
    
    select.addEventListener("focus", event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      focusinSpan.textContent = parseInt(focusinSpan.textContent) + 1;
    });    
    
    select.addEventListener("focusout", event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      focusoutSpan.textContent = parseInt(focusoutSpan.textContent) + 1;
    });
```

```html
  <select id="test" class="test">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  mousedown event is clicked:<span id="mousedown">0</span> times<br/>
  focusin event is clicked:<span id="focusin">0</span> times<br/>
  focusout event is clicked:<span id="focusout">0</span> times<br/>
```

Comment: Just add `disabled` attribute to the select element, works in all browsers.

Comment: @Teemu Forgot to mention that. For accessibility reasons disabled attribute can't be used.

Comment: What's the difference if you disable the element with JS instead of HTML?

Comment: @Teemo Select still will still be focusable element and the screen readers will read its accessibility state. It is used only for this.

Comment: I don't quite get it. You want to disable a drop-down, but still keep it accessible ... Also, if the drop-down is focusable, it's also in the tabbing order, desktop users can tab to the element, hit Space, and use arrow keys to navigate through the options and hit Enter to select an item.

Comment: @Teemu we tried to made this with with div element but not everything was read out correctly. Space and arrow keys are also disabled.

Comment: There's `label` element which can be connected to a specific form control, that probably works better than a div. But still, why should be screen readers able to read an element which can't be used ..?

Comment: The idea is that we have additional div element with custom navigation, custom dropdown, and other... We need this only for accessibility purpose.